# REGEXP to convert any 3 chars or less word to wordVVV

Tags: php, regex, multibyte-functions

I am trying to convert any occurrence of a word with 3 chars or less to the same word with the string VVV attached to it.
Example: for -> forVVV
I am using none Latin chars (UTF8), hence the MB.
What I have is:

```
$pattern='\b[.{1,6}]\b';
$text=mb_ereg_replace($pattern,'\0VVV',$text,'me');
```

What am I missing?

Here is a case study, see it catches nothing:

```
$text="א אב אבי אביהו מדינה שול של";
$pattern='/\b.{1,6}\b/um';
$text=preg_replace($pattern,'hhh',$text);
echo $text;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pattern's not detecting or grouping things right.

Use `\w` for word-characters and standard parenthesis instead of square brackets, and you're not evaluating PHP code in the replacement, you're simply referring to captured text segments, so don't need the `e` flag:

```
$pattern = '\b(\w{1,3})\b';
$text = mb_ereg_replace($pattern, '\0VVV', $text, 'm');
```

Alternatively, use `preg_replace` with the unicode flag:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\b\w{1,3}\b/um', '\0VVV', $text)
```

If you need to cater for arabic and right-to-left characters, you need to us unicode character properties instead of `\w` and `\b` (`\w` doesn't match letters from all languages, and `\b` only matches between `\w\W` and `\W\w` - which are both broken wrt. non-latin languages.)

Try this intead:

```
$text = preg_replace('/(?
```

(and again cos I can't tell whether I need to encode < or not)

```
$text = preg_replace('/(?<!\PL)(\pL{1,3})(?:\PL)/um', '\1VVV', $text);
```

Comment: Nop, something is still wrong, check the question, I added an actual code snippet that shows the problem.

Comment: I've editted the ansewr to include examples using `\pL` and `\PL` with negative look-ahead and look-behind assertions substituting for the latin-only `\b` word-boundary detection.

Answer (score 0):

This should match what you want?

```
\b(?<Match>\w{1,3})\b
```